# How to verify an user input that can be a String (five) or a int (5)?

Tags: string, int, drjava

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class shirt
{
  public static void main(String[] args)  
   {    
   Scanner userinput = new Scanner (System.in);

String nbshirts;

System.out.println("How many shirts do you have");

nshirts = userinput.next();

if (nbshirts.equals("five"))
{

System.out.println("Just like me !");
}

else 
{
   System.out.println("We don't have the same number of shirt");
} 
  }
  }
```

Hello, what I would like is the possibility that the if/else statement validate the input if it is five or 5. I don't know what to add/how to proceed to create a single dialogue box where both five and 5 would be accepted as true value.
Hope you can help me ! 
:)

Answer (score 1):

If the variable you are checking is `nbshirts` then this should work:

```
if(nbshirts.equals("five") || "5".equals(nbshirts))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No need to parse the integer. `"5".equals(nbshirts)`

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this is much cleaner!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Honestly I did not think of presenting 5 as a String too. I was trying to make this work with 5 as an integer.